# Query items of a collection before a certain date on Fauna Db?

Tags: faunadb

I looked on google and tried different thing but I cannot figure out how to query all the item of a collection that have the key dueDate before the a **certain Date**.

On Mysql I would do something like :
`select * from table_name where dueDate < "2001-01-01 00:00:00"`

That query on mysql would return the items with the Date Inferior to 2001-01-01

I tried to do use that query on Fauna :

```
q.Map(
 q.Paginate( 
  q.Match(q.Index(indexesQuery1)),
  { before: Date('2021-01-15T17:34:00+08:00')
 } ),
 q.Lambda("X", q.Get(q.Var("X"))) ) )
```

**indexQuery1** is : getNewWordDemoIso(dueDate: Date!)

But It returns an empty Array,

Also I saved all my Date all Fauna the date format called : iso 8601

Also Im using javascript

Any ideas !?

thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

When you perform an "Create", you need parse your ISOString Date for an FaunaDB Date format.

You migth need something like this:

```
 const newTransaction = await fauna.query<TransactionObject>(
          q.Create(q.Collection("transactions"), {
            data: { 
              ...transaction,
              firstDueDate: q.Date(transaction.firstDueDate),
              lastDueDate: q.Date(transaction.lastDueDate),
              createdAt: q.ToDate(q.Now())
            }
          })
        );
```

This will work for you as you said you are using JS/TS.

ps: (import {query as q} from 'faunadb')